# How to update a JPanel with another JPanel from another class in the same project?

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jfreechart, netbeans-7

I have created (with Netbeans) a JFrame and I put two JPanels (mainPanel and secondPanel)in it.
One other class of the project returns a JPanel when I open a file using JFrame's Menu Bar.
How do I update the mainPanel , so that it shows the JPanel that is returned from the other class of the project?
Thank you.

```
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package nysemarketpick;

import java.io.File;
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

/**
 *
 * @author skiabox
 */
public class MainForm extends JFrame {

/**
 * Creates new form MainForm
 */
public MainForm() {
    initComponents();
}

/**
 * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
 * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
 * regenerated by the Form Editor.
 */
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">
private void initComponents() {

    fileChooser = new javax.swing.JFileChooser();
    toolbar = new javax.swing.JToolBar();
    shortButton = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jSeparator1 = new javax.swing.JToolBar.Separator();
    midButton = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jSeparator2 = new javax.swing.JToolBar.Separator();
    longButton = new javax.swing.JButton();
    mainPanel = new javax.swing.JPanel();
    secondPanel = new javax.swing.JPanel();
    jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jMenuBar1 = new javax.swing.JMenuBar();
    fileMenu = new javax.swing.JMenu();
    Open = new javax.swing.JMenuItem();
    Exit = new javax.swing.JMenuItem();
    optionsMenu = new javax.swing.JMenu();
    shortItem = new javax.swing.JMenuItem();
    midItem = new javax.swing.JMenuItem();
    longItem = new javax.swing.JMenuItem();
    toolsMenu = new javax.swing.JMenu();
    helpMenu = new javax.swing.JMenu();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setTitle("Nyse Stock Pick");

    toolbar.setFloatable(false);
    toolbar.setRollover(true);

    shortButton.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/nysemarketpick/S-orange-icon.png"))); // NOI18N
    shortButton.setText("Short-Term");
    shortButton.setFocusable(false);
    shortButton.setHorizontalTextPosition(javax.swing.SwingConstants.RIGHT);
    shortButton.setVerticalTextPosition(javax.swing.SwingConstants.BOTTOM);
    toolbar.add(shortButton);
    toolbar.add(jSeparator1);

    midButton.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/nysemarketpick/M-lg-icon.png"))); // NOI18N
    midButton.setText("Mid-Term");
    midButton.setFocusable(false);
    midButton.setHorizontalTextPosition(javax.swing.SwingConstants.RIGHT);
    midButton.setVerticalTextPosition(javax.swing.SwingConstants.BOTTOM);
    toolbar.add(midButton);
    toolbar.add(jSeparator2);

    longButton.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/nysemarketpick/L-blue-icon.png"))); // NOI18N
    longButton.setText("Long-Term");
    longButton.setFocusable(false);
    longButton.setHorizontalTextPosition(javax.swing.SwingConstants.RIGHT);
    longButton.setVerticalTextPosition(javax.swing.SwingConstants.BOTTOM);
    toolbar.add(longButton);

    org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout mainPanelLayout = new org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout(mainPanel);
    mainPanel.setLayout(mainPanelLayout);
    mainPanelLayout.setHorizontalGroup(
        mainPanelLayout.createParallelGroup(org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.LEADING)
        .add(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );
    mainPanelLayout.setVerticalGroup(
        mainPanelLayout.createParallelGroup(org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.LEADING)
        .add(0, 537, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );

    org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout secondPanelLayout = new org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout(secondPanel);
    secondPanel.setLayout(secondPanelLayout);
    secondPanelLayout.setHorizontalGroup(
        secondPanelLayout.createParallelGroup(org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.LEADING)
        .add(0, 240, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );
    secondPanelLayout.setVerticalGroup(
        secondPanelLayout.createParallelGroup(org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.LEADING)
        .add(0, 543, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );

    jLabel1.setText("World Market Status");
    jLabel1.setHorizontalTextPosition(javax.swing.SwingConstants.RIGHT);

    fileMenu.setText("File");

    Open.setText("Open");
    Open.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            OpenActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });
    fileMenu.add(Open);

    Exit.setText(" Exit");
    Exit.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            ExitActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });
    fileMenu.add(Exit);

    jMenuBar1.add(fileMenu);

    optionsMenu.setText("Options");

    shortItem.setText("Short-Term Moving Average");
    optionsMenu.add(shortItem);

    midItem.setText("Mid-Term Moving Average");
    optionsMenu.add(midItem);

    longItem.setText("Long-Term Moving Average");
    optionsMenu.add(longItem);

    jMenuBar1.add(optionsMenu);

    toolsMenu.setText("Tools");
    jMenuBar1.add(toolsMenu);

    helpMenu.setText("Help");
    jMenuBar1.add(helpMenu);

    setJMenuBar(jMenuBar1);

    org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout layout = new org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.LEADING)
        .add(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .add(layout.createParallelGroup(org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.LEADING)
                .add(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .add(toolbar, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addPreferredGap(org.jdesktop.layout.LayoutStyle.RELATED, 762, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .add(jLabel1, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 182, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .add(354, 354, 354))
                .add(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .add(6, 6, 6)
                    .add(mainPanel, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .add(18, 18, 18)
                    .add(secondPanel, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .add(351, 351, 351))))
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.LEADING)
        .add(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .add(layout.createParallelGroup(org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.LEADING, false)
                .add(toolbar, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 25, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .add(jLabel1, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
            .add(12, 12, 12)
            .add(layout.createParallelGroup(org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.LEADING)
                .add(mainPanel, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .add(secondPanel, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
            .addContainerGap(33, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );

    pack();
}// </editor-fold>

private void ExitActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                     
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    System.exit(0);
}                                    

private void OpenActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                     
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    int returnVal = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(this);
    if (returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION)
    {
        File file = fileChooser.getSelectedFile();


        //What to do with the file
        //remove current chart
        mainPanel.removeAll();
        //add new chart
        PriceVolumeChart chart = new PriceVolumeChart(file.getAbsolutePath());

        mainPanel.add(chart.getChart());
        mainPanel.validate();
    }
}                                    

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String args[]) {
    /*
     * Set the Nimbus look and feel
     */
    //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
    /*
     * If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the
     * default look and feel. For details see
     * http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html
     */
    try {
        for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
            if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(MainForm.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(MainForm.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(MainForm.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(MainForm.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    //</editor-fold>

    /*
     * Create and display the form
     */
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

        public void run() {
            new MainForm().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}
// Variables declaration - do not modify
private javax.swing.JMenuItem Exit;
private javax.swing.JMenuItem Open;
private javax.swing.JFileChooser fileChooser;
private javax.swing.JMenu fileMenu;
private javax.swing.JMenu helpMenu;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
private javax.swing.JMenuBar jMenuBar1;
private javax.swing.JToolBar.Separator jSeparator1;
private javax.swing.JToolBar.Separator jSeparator2;
private javax.swing.JButton longButton;
private javax.swing.JMenuItem longItem;
private javax.swing.JPanel mainPanel;
private javax.swing.JButton midButton;
private javax.swing.JMenuItem midItem;
private javax.swing.JMenu optionsMenu;
private javax.swing.JPanel secondPanel;
private javax.swing.JButton shortButton;
private javax.swing.JMenuItem shortItem;
private javax.swing.JToolBar toolbar;
private javax.swing.JMenu toolsMenu;
// End of variables declaration
}



public class PriceVolumeChart
{
static FileReader fileReader;
static File file;
static TimeSeries t1 = new TimeSeries("49-day moving average");
static String filename;

JPanel myPanel;

/**
 * Default constructor
 */
public PriceVolumeChart(String absoluteFilePath)
{
    //super(title);
    filename = absoluteFilePath;
    //JPanel panel = createDemoPanel();
    //panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 270));
    //setContentPane(panel);
    myPanel = createDemoPanel();
    myPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 270));
}


//create price dataset
//hard-coded here
private static OHLCDataset createPriceDataset(String filename)
{
    //the following data is taken from http://finance.yahoo.com/
    //for demo purposes...


    OHLCSeries s1 = new OHLCSeries(filename);

    try {
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename));
        DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd");
        String inputLine;
        in.readLine();
        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
            StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(inputLine, ",");
            Date date       = df.parse( st.nextToken() );
            double open     = Double.parseDouble( st.nextToken() );
            double high     = Double.parseDouble( st.nextToken() );
            double low      = Double.parseDouble( st.nextToken() );
            double close    = Double.parseDouble( st.nextToken() );
            double volume   = Double.parseDouble( st.nextToken() );
            //double adjClose = Double.parseDouble( st.nextToken() );
            s1.add(new Day(date), open, high, low, close);
            t1.add(new Day(date), close);
        }
        in.close();
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }



    OHLCSeriesCollection dataset = new OHLCSeriesCollection();
    dataset.addSeries(s1);

    return dataset;
}


//create volume dataset
private static IntervalXYDataset createVolumeDataset(String filename)
{
    //create dataset 2...
    TimeSeries s1 = new TimeSeries("Volume");

    try {
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename));
        DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd");
        String inputLine;
        in.readLine();
        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
            StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(inputLine, ",");
            Date date = df.parse( st.nextToken() );
            st.nextToken();
            st.nextToken();
            st.nextToken();
            st.nextToken();
            double volume   = Double.parseDouble( st.nextToken() );
            //double adjClose = Double.parseDouble( st.nextToken() );
            s1.add(new Day(date), volume);
        }
        in.close();
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }



    return new TimeSeriesCollection(s1);
}


private static JFreeChart createCombinedChart()
{
    OHLCDataset data1 = createPriceDataset(filename);

    XYItemRenderer renderer1 = new HighLowRenderer();
    renderer1.setBaseToolTipGenerator(new StandardXYToolTipGenerator(StandardXYToolTipGenerator.DEFAULT_TOOL_TIP_FORMAT, new SimpleDateFormat("d-MMM-yyyy"), new DecimalFormat("0.00")));
    renderer1.setSeriesPaint(0, Color.blue);
    DateAxis domainAxis = new DateAxis("Date");
    NumberAxis rangeAxis = new NumberAxis("Price");
    rangeAxis.setNumberFormatOverride(new DecimalFormat("$0.00"));
    rangeAxis.setAutoRange(true);
    rangeAxis.setAutoRangeIncludesZero(false);
    XYPlot plot1 = new XYPlot(data1, domainAxis, rangeAxis, renderer1);
    plot1.setBackgroundPaint(Color.lightGray);
    plot1.setDomainGridlinePaint(Color.white);
    plot1.setRangeGridlinePaint(Color.white);
    plot1.setRangePannable(true);

    //Overlay the Long-Term Trend Indicator
    TimeSeries dataset3 = MovingAverage.createMovingAverage(t1, "LT", 49, 49);
    TimeSeriesCollection collection = new TimeSeriesCollection();
    collection.addSeries(dataset3);
    plot1.setDataset(1, collection);
    plot1.setRenderer(1, new StandardXYItemRenderer());



    //add a second dataset (volume) and renderer
    IntervalXYDataset data2 = createVolumeDataset(filename);
    XYBarRenderer renderer2 = new XYBarRenderer();
    renderer2.setDrawBarOutline(false);
    renderer2.setBaseToolTipGenerator(new StandardXYToolTipGenerator(StandardXYToolTipGenerator.DEFAULT_TOOL_TIP_FORMAT, new SimpleDateFormat("d-MMM-yyyy"), new DecimalFormat("0,000.00")));
    renderer2.setSeriesPaint(0, Color.red);

    XYPlot plot2 = new XYPlot(data2, null, new NumberAxis("Volume"), renderer2);
    plot2.setBackgroundPaint(Color.lightGray);
    plot2.setDomainGridlinePaint(Color.white);
    plot2.setRangeGridlinePaint(Color.white);

    //middle pane oscillators
    TimeSeries threeMA = MovingAverage.createMovingAverage(t1, "SL1", 3, 3);
    TimeSeries tenMA = MovingAverage.createMovingAverage(t1, "SL2", 10, 10);

    List<TimeSeriesDataItem> threeItemsList = new ArrayList<TimeSeriesDataItem>();
    List<TimeSeriesDataItem> tenItemsList = new ArrayList<TimeSeriesDataItem>();
    threeItemsList = threeMA.getItems();
    tenItemsList = tenMA.getItems();

    for (TimeSeriesDataItem item: threeItemsList)
    {
        System.out.println("three" + item.getValue().doubleValue() + " " + item.getPeriod().toString());
    }

    for (TimeSeriesDataItem item: tenItemsList)
    {
        System.out.println("ten" + item.getValue().doubleValue() + " " + item.getPeriod().toString());
    }

    TimeSeries slDataset = new TimeSeries("SL");
    int i = 0;
    //List<TimeSeriesDataItem> slItemsList = new ArrayList<TimeSeriesDataItem>();
    TimeSeriesDataItem myItem;
    Day threeDate;

    for (TimeSeriesDataItem item: threeItemsList)
    {
        //RegularTimePeriod variable = item.getPeriod();
        if (item.getPeriod().compareTo(tenItemsList.get(0).getPeriod()) < 0)
        {
            continue;
        }
        else
        {
            double result = item.getValue().doubleValue() - tenItemsList.get(i).getValue().doubleValue();
            Day currentDay = (Day)item.getPeriod();
            myItem = new TimeSeriesDataItem(currentDay, result);
            slDataset.add(myItem);

            //slItemsList.add(myItem);
            i++;
        }


    }

    System.out.println("slDataset count : " + slDataset.getItemCount());



    TimeSeriesCollection collectionSL = new TimeSeriesCollection();
    collectionSL.addSeries(slDataset);

    //create middle line (ML)
    XYLineAndShapeRenderer rendererFinal = new XYLineAndShapeRenderer(true, false);
    rendererFinal.setBaseShapesVisible(false);
    TimeSeries ml = MovingAverage.createMovingAverage(slDataset, "ML", 16, 16);
    TimeSeriesCollection collectionML = new TimeSeriesCollection();
    collectionML.addSeries(ml);

    DateAxis domainMiddleAxis = new DateAxis();
    NumberAxis rangeMiddleAxis = new NumberAxis("Value");
    StandardXYItemRenderer rendererMiddle = new StandardXYItemRenderer();
    rendererMiddle.setBaseShapesVisible(false);
    //rendererMiddle.setBaseToolTipGenerator(new StandardXYToolTipGenerator(StandardXYToolTipGenerator.DEFAULT_TOOL_TIP_FORMAT, new SimpleDateFormat("d-MMM-yyyy"), new DecimalFormat("0.00")));
    XYPlot plot3 = new XYPlot(collectionSL, domainMiddleAxis, rangeMiddleAxis, rendererFinal);
    plot3.setBackgroundPaint(Color.lightGray);
    plot3.setDomainGridlinePaint(Color.white);
    plot3.setRangeGridlinePaint(Color.white);
    plot3.setRangePannable(true);
    plot3.setDomainPannable(true);



    //plot3.setDataset(collectionSL);
    //plot3.setRenderer(new StandardXYItemRenderer());
    //StandardXYItemRenderer rendererML = new StandardXYItemRenderer();
    plot3.setDataset(1, collectionML);
    plot3.setRenderer(1, rendererMiddle);
    //XYLineAndShapeRenderer r = new XYLineAndShapeRenderer();
    //r.setBaseShapesVisible(false);
    //plot3.setRenderer(1, r);



    CombinedDomainXYPlot cplot = new CombinedDomainXYPlot(domainAxis);
    cplot.add(plot1, 3);
    cplot.add(plot3, 2);
    cplot.add(plot2, 2);
    cplot.setGap(8.0);
    cplot.setDomainGridlinePaint(Color.white);
    cplot.setDomainGridlinesVisible(true);
    cplot.setDomainPannable(true);


    //return the new combined chart
    JFreeChart chart = new JFreeChart("Sun Microsystems (SUNW)", JFreeChart.DEFAULT_TITLE_FONT, cplot, true);


    ChartUtilities.applyCurrentTheme(chart);
    renderer2.setShadowVisible(false);
    renderer2.setBarPainter(new StandardXYBarPainter());

    return chart;
}


//create a panel
public static JPanel createDemoPanel()
{
    JFreeChart chart = createCombinedChart();
    ChartPanel panel = new ChartPanel(chart);
    panel.setMouseWheelEnabled(true);

    return panel;
}

//return chart
public JPanel getChart()
{
    return myPanel;
}

}
```

Comment: Could you provide a code sample?

Comment: Ok , I will update the original post.

Comment: It seems that not using a layout manager on the JFrame level is a disadvantage

Comment: What do you mean by **One other class of the project returns a JPanel when I open a file using JFrame's Menu Bar ?** Do you mean you get a reference of the said Class ?

Comment: I open the txt file an the other class(PriceVolumeChart) is responsible for returning a chart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it seems you want to use mainPanel as the panel containing the chart. Instead of assigning panels to the mainPanel, try to add and remove panels in it. make it be the container and don't try to change it by assigning another Jpanel to the variable.

in the method "private void OpenActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)" try to change the following:

```
//What to do with the file
PriceVolumeChart chart = new PriceVolumeChart(file.getAbsolutePath());
mainPanel = chart.getChart();
```

to:

```
//remove current chart
mainPanel.removeAll(); //assuming you have nothing else in main panel other than a chart panel;
//add new chart
PriceVolumeChart chart = new PriceVolumeChart(file.getAbsolutePath());
mainPanel.add(chart);
mainPanel.validate();
```

NOTE NOTE: i did not come with this my self. the idea was taken from here : [Change a JPanel dynamically based on JRadioButton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9233394/change-a-jpanel-dynamically-based-on-jradiobutton)

I modified it to where i thought fits in your code.
i just used same code as the original question and therefore maybe you should also try what was suggested in the answers as it looks like the correct way.

EDIT:

in your after making the changes in your code, as you commented, add the following also:

in the function

```
public MainForm() {
    initComponents();
}
```

replace the layout manager of the main panel after the components have initialized. for example:

```
public MainForm() {
    initComponents();
    mainPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
}
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work.I don't know what am I doing wrong.I will update the original post code with the new code.

Comment: @trashgod : maybe you can help here with your expertise

Answer (score 0):

I've used the following code and it worked for me:

```
JPanel tempPanel = new YourPanelClass();
tempPanel.setBounds(DisplayPanel.getBounds()); // DisplayPanel is a panel object with which you want to replace new Panel.
mainPanel.removeAll(); //mainPanel is container for panels
mainPanel.revalidate();
mainPanel.repaint();
mainPanel.add(tempPanel);
```